# Custom Validator Reactive Form Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, customvalidator

this is the first time I have used custom validators. I followed this guide https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/forms-and-validation-in-ionic . Basically I want to check if the username is already in use and if so the Update Profile button is not enabled. But it doesn't work, if I try to enter in the form a username that already exists in the Real time database of firebase the button is enabled, but in the console I get the message "username già in uso". Am I doing something wrong with the UsernameValidator class?

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
export class UsernameValidator {
    static validUsername(fc: FormControl){
        firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild("username")
        .equalTo(fc.value)
        .once("value",snapshot => {
          if (snapshot.exists()){
            console.log("username già in uso")
            return ({validUsername: false});         
            }
          else
            return (null);           
        });
    }
}
```

This is where I define the form group and validators:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, 
              public pfService: ProfileService, public fb: FormBuilder,
              public authService: AuthenticationService) 
  {
    this.id = this.authService.userData.uid;
    //Underscore and dot can't be next to each other (e.g user_.name).
    //Underscore or dot can't be used multiple times in a row (e.g user__name / user..name).
    this.validPattern = "^(?=.{6,20}$)(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-z0-9._]+$"; 
    this.validPatternName = "^[a-z]{3,10}$";
    this.userForm = fb.group({
      txtUsername:  ["",[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.validPattern),
                                                  UsernameValidator.validUsername]],
      txtName:     ["",[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.validPatternName)]],
    });
  };
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="updateForm()" >
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label class="form-control" position="floating">Userame</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="txtUsername" type="text" ></ion-input>
    <span [hidden]="userForm.controls.txtUsername.valid || userForm.controls.txtUsername.pristine">Lunghezza tra 6 e 20 caratteri</span>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label class="form-control" position="floating">Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="txtName" type="text" > </ion-input>
    <span [hidden]="userForm.controls.txtName.valid || userForm.controls.txtName.pristine">Lunghezza tra 6 e 20 caratteri</span>   
  </ion-item>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-button type="submit" *ngIf="userForm.controls.txtUsername.valid && userForm.controls.txtName.valid " color="primary" shape="full" expand="block">Update Profile</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest that your validator returns :

```
 return ({validUsername: true});
```

if you want to check the validator state each time you type a character in your input, I suggest to add in the contructor after your form declaration :

```
 this.userForm .valueChanges.subscribe(()=> {
console.log(this.userForm.getError('validUsername'))
})
```

Also, maybe your validator won't return anything as it going to get stucked inside the snnapshot, you will know if your userForm.getError('validUsername') still return null even if you got "username già in uso".

Comment: Hi Patrick, thank you for your reply. I modified the validator return and added what you said. You are right, it returns null even when there is "username già in uso". Strange, how could I make it not block in the snapshot?

Comment: Hi @ChrisCv,
Did you see my answer ?

Comment: Hi Patrick, yes, thank you, I have accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

As your firebase query is an async function, try this :

```
 static validUsername(fc: FormControl){
        firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild("username")
        .equalTo(fc.value)
        .once("value",async snapshot => {
          if (snapshot.exists()){
            console.log("username già in uso")
           return await ({validUsername: true});         
            }
          else
            return (null);           
        });
    }
```

or

```
static validUsername(fc: FormControl){
     let bool:boolean =this.getSnapshot(fc.value)
          if(bool===true)

           return  ({validUsername: true});         
            }
          else{
            return (null); 
             }          
        });
    }
async getSnapshot(value:string):boolean{
let bool:boolean
 await firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild("username")
        .equalTo(fc.value)
        .once("value",snapshot => {
          if (snapshot.exists()){
            bool=true
            console.log("username già in uso")               
            }
          else{
              bool=false
             }
                   
        });
}
```